# What address families can getaddrinfo return?

Tags: macos, sockets, unix, winsock

When I call `getaddrinfo` with `AF_UNSPEC`, it can theoretically return any address families it likes: `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6`, maybe AppleTalk, bluetooth, datalink, netlink addresses...

In practice, it just returns `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` on most platforms:

- On FreeBSD, it can only return `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` (checked in source)
- On linux, ditto (according to glibc manpage)
- On Windows, similarly, "A value of AF_UNSPEC for ai_family indicates the caller will accept only the AF_INET and AF_INET6 address families." [[MSDN, getaddrinfo]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What about other systems? Are there platforms where we might get other address structures?

I'm particularly suspicious of MacOS - the source seems to be missing from opensource.apple.com/source/Libc and the manpage doesn't say. We have an unreproducible log file from a Mac test run that may indicate getaddrinfo returned some other address family. Other platforms we support are AIX, Solaris, HP-UX.

I'm aware I can just check the family in the structure returned. I can't guess what interesting strings and hints might need to be used to get non-AF_INET(6) results out though.

Comment: Well, `netdb.h` seems to indicate that a `struct addrinfo`'s `ai_family` could be any "`PF_xxx`", so maybe it could be anything?  That seems far from a definitive answer, though... commenting in case that's a helpful place to look.  Also, the man page does make a reference to setting `ai_family` to `PF_UNSPEC` in the hints...  Now, if it would just enumerate what "any protocol family supported by the operating system" was.  :)  There's further reference in the Examples section that it *can* be other values, but I (like you) don't see *which* other values... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee of any kind. When I have invented my own protocol and assigned a number (locally), and my protocol can resolve the name your program gave, it is permissible to return a `sockaddr` for my address family.

Basically, if you pass `AF_UNSPEC`, you can do either of two things:

1. live dangerously, assume that `PF_*` constants map to `AF_*` constants, create a socket of that type and connect it, giving you instant support for my homebrew protocol, or, *better*,
2. ignore any result that has an address family you do not understand and proceed to the next one.

You need to be aware that it is quite possible that a name can be looked up but has no addresses of the desired type. When doing a lookup with `AF_UNSPEC`, you will get a positive lookup result then and need to create the error condition yourself.

As the ideal behaviour for an app is to fall back on other results in case the first one is not working (think DNS round-robin with a failed server), this can be achieved by iterating over the results until one succeeds and adjusting the error cause (i.e. start with "no addresses of required type", and if you find one and connection fails, switch to "destination unreachable").

Comment: There's no _cross-platform_ guarantee in POSIX. There are platform-specific guarantees. For example, it's _guaranteed_ that getaddrinfo only returns AF_INET(6) on Windows and BSD. I'm asking for specific documentation or libc source code to say which families are returned on MacOS. Not "there may be others", but which others. If MacOS libc can return eg AppleTalk addresses, show me the code on opensource.apple.com.

Comment: No, there is no platform guarantee either, as the network stack is modular on each of these, so new protocols can be hooked into them. I can have an out-of-tree Linux kernel module that implements my address family, and a libc Name Service Switch (NSS) module that adds the resolver, and this is sufficient to add new results to `getaddrinfo` output.

Comment: You're right, thanks. This still doesn't really answer the question what address families you'd _actually_ get out on a typical Mac machine, for instance.

Comment: I'd expect `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` on typical setups, and `AF_APPLETALK` in some business environments. The other protocols typically have a different resolver API.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX says "If the ai_family field to which hints points has the value AF_UNSPEC, addresses shall be returned for use with any address family that can be used with the specified nodename and/or servname." ([POSIX getaddrinfo(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html)) and "A value of AF_UNSPEC for ai_family means that the caller shall accept any address family."

In fact, even the linux manpage doesn't exactly match what you say: "either IPv4 or IPv6, **for example**"; OpenBSD says "When ai_family
                    is set to PF_UNSPEC, it means the caller will accept any
                    protocol family supported by the operating system.", so I'll take it that it just means "whatever" (compatible with the other parameters).

I really don't know what strings one should pass getaddrinfo, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The range of AF_* values that can be returned is limited only by the size of the struct's type.  It is perfectly legitimate for a custom driver/network to return its own addresses.  You, of course, are limited to those you have headers for to match the arbitrary values against so as to understand the semantics of using a particular endpoint.

While you could try to create a total enumeration of all possible AF_* symbols, without a header that defines its value to match what the OS drivers are using to designate that protocol, the names are meaningless.  Here are just a few that I found:

AF_IPX, AF_APPLETALK, AF_NETROM, AF_BRIDGE, AF_AAL5, AF_X25, AF_BRIDGE, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_DECnet, AF_ATMPVC, AF_ROSE, AF_NETBEUI, AF_NETLINK, AF_ASH, AF_ECONET, AF_ATM_SVC, AF_SNA, AF_IRDA, AF_PPPOX, AF_WANPIPE, AF_LLC, etc, etc, etc.

Linux, being linux, has most of those in socket.h, but those values aren't guaranteed to be valid outside of that kernel and those drivers.

Comment: No, "custom drivers" most certainly don't contribute to getaddrinfo's results. There's no kernel support for this stuff at all; it all comes down to what libc does. On linux and BSD, libc does some parsing, creates sockets and sends/unpacks DNS queries, then returns the results. On these platforms, it's impossible for anything other than AF_INET to be returned, unless the system has a hacked-up version of glibc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm intentionally conflating bits about protocol families which can be dynamic via the kernel and are used to match up drivers and address families. And yes address resolution is entirely inside user space, however my point is that under POSIX any list if either AF_* and PF_ is entirely system dependent and it would be perfectly legitimate to supply either or both in a custom network.